# Extra vertical space inside mdframed theorem environment

Tags: spacing, mdframed

I have seen several similar questions on TeX.SE of a similar nature, but none of them seem to address my precise issue. I have been working with `mdframed` environments for a while. I read that there were some issues with older versions, so I updated to the latest version, 1.9b, but it seems to have introduced a spacing issue that I did not have before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

The output, zoomed in, is seen here:

[image]

There is more vertical space above the contents than below. This only began after I fully updated my TeX distribution, so I assume that this possibly changed how `mdframed` works. Any ideas? Obviously I can manually change the spacing to fix this, but I'm looking to diagnose the problem, if there is one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The culprit is not `mdframed` but `amsthm`.

In fact, the following example without `amsthm`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

To obtain the style you want, you can redefine the `definition` style in this way:

```
\newtheoremstyle{definition}% <name>
  {-\topsep}%                 <space above>
  {}%                         <space below>
  {\normalfont}%              <body font>
  {}%                         <indent amount>
  {\bfseries}%                <theorem head font>
  {.}%                        <punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}%                     <space after theorem head>
  {}%                         <theorem head spec>
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}% <name>
  {-\topsep}%                 <space above>
  {}%                         <space below>
  {\normalfont}%              <body font>
  {}%                         <indent amount>
  {\bfseries}%                <theorem head font>
  {.}%                        <punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}%                     <space after theorem head>
  {}%                         <theorem head spec>
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic. Now I'm left wondering what changed when I updated the amsthm package...

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong -- since the last released update to `amsthm` was july 2009, and the last functional update was august 2004 (which, i believe, was before `mdframed` even existed), i seriously doubt that your updating `amsthm` was the cause of the recent change in your output.  however, since this is a recognized deficit in the behavior of `amsthm + mdframed`, it has been added to the list of requests for action when `amsthm` and the ams document classes are next overhauled.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for the info. This makes my problem even more confusing, I suppose, because the spacing issue clearly did not exist before I updated. I was using a MikTeX distribution from 2011.

Comment: i don't suppose you still have a log file from the version that was working.  if you did, you could make a list of the packages used with their reported dates, then compare those with the versions reported for the newer run with the problem.  (using `\listfiles` makes collecting this information easier, but if you don't have the ability to rerun an old attempt, that's not a particularly useful suggestion.)  but if you *could* get that information, i'd be interested.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, sadly, I do not have the log files anymore. The only proof I have that I'm not going crazy is the final PDF output from the old version. Oh well. It was probably some perfect combination of bugs from random packages unrelated to `amsthm`...

Comment: @karlkoeller Why not to set the space below to `-\topsep` as well? Or rather, why is it not giving any trouble in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: This appears to be a bug in certain versions of mdframed!

```
mdframed.sty 2013/03/09 1.8:  Good
mdframed.sty 2013/07/01 1.9b: Bad
mdframed.sty 2013/08/18 1.9d: Good
```

Note that you can get the latest version of mdframed from https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed