# Space between text and upper line in mdframed

Tags: spacing, environments, margins, mdframed

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1.1pt]{Definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition} (blah blah)\newline
Text...
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Is it possible to reduce the space between the first line of text and the upper black line?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Similar question: [Extra vertical space inside mdframed theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171811/79060). The [`mdframed.sty` v1.9d](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/blob/master/mdframed.sty) on GitHub has fixed this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extra vertical space inside mdframed theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168642/extra-vertical-space-inside-mdframed-theorem-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this better?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1.1pt, innertopmargin=-2pt, innerbottommargin=7pt]{Definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition} (blah blah)\newline
Text...
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This adds more magic numbers (`-2pt`, `7pt`) and I personally not recommend handling problems this way.

Answer (score 2):

That extra top skip is produced by `\topskip`. Reduce `\topskip` from `mdframed` option `innertopmargin`'s default value (`5pt`) solves the problem..

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}   % provide \theoremstyle
\usepackage{mdframed}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[
    linewidth=1.1pt, 
    innertopmargin=\dimexpr5pt-\topskip\relax]
  {Definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\begin{Definition} (blah blah)\newline
  Text...
\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

[image: theorem env defined by mdframed, with normal top skip]